# Oracle xmltable parsing return LPX-00209

Tags: oracle, xpath, oracle11g, xml-parsing, xmltable

i'm newbie in Oracle. Right now i'm trying to parse XML and put it inside VK_ACCOUNTS table.
My xml sample is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response list="true">
 <account>
  <account_id>1656672360</account_id>
  <account_type>general</account_type>
  <account_status>1</account_status>
  <access_role>reports</access_role>
 </account>
</response>
```

I request  xml with function below and as far as i see it returns xml properly:

```
create or replace function GET_CLOBFROMURL(
  p_url     varchar2,
  p_charset varchar2 default 'UTF8'
) return clob
is
  req   utl_http.req; 
  resp  utl_http.resp;
  val   varchar2(32547);
  a     clob;
BEGIN
  a:='';
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(a,true);
  dbms_lob.open(a,dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);
  req := utl_http.begin_request(p_url);
  utl_http.set_body_charset(req, p_charset);
  resp := utl_http.get_response(req);
  LOOP
    a := a||val;
    utl_http.read_text(resp, val, 5000);
  END LOOP;
  utl_http.end_response(resp);
  return a;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN utl_http.end_of_body THEN
    utl_http.end_response(resp);
    return a;
  WHEN others then
    utl_http.end_response(resp);
    raise;
END;
```

And get xml to xml_clob

```
xml_clob := tableau.get_clobFromUrl(REQUEST);
    IF xml_clob != EMPTY_CLOB() THEN
    insert into tableau.VK_ACCOUNTS(account_id, account_type, account_status, access_role)
        SELECT
        proc.account_id,
        proc.account_type,
        proc.account_status,
        proc.access_role   
        FROM XMLTABLE('response/account' passing (select xmltype(xml_clob)  resp FROM dual)
            columns account_id number             path '/account/account_id',
                    account_type varchar2(20)     path '/account/account_type',
                    account_status number         path '/account/account_status',
                    access_role varchar2(20)      path '/account/access_role'
                ) proc;
      COMMIT;     
    END IF;
END;
```

Finally i get an error:

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML
LPX-00209: PI names starting with XML are reserved
Error at line 3
ORA-06512: на  "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
ORA-06512: на  line 1
ORA-06512: на  "TABLEAU.VK_LOADDATA", line 11
ORA-06512: на  line 2
```

What i have already tried is TRIM function for XML but it doesn't help me.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Oracle`, but I suppose you should try to rename `xml_clob` into `clob_xml`

Comment: Hi @Andersson, thx but as far as i know, it's just a naming of variable and i can name it how i want with pretty small limitations. No?

Comment: It's simple suggestion: I've just check the line from exception log `names starting with XML are reserved`

Comment: checked it, not working:( thx

Comment: Why are you getting a CLOB? Why not just declare a httpuritype variable for the URL and use its GETXML() method? Examples in the [http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb15dbu.htm#ADXDB5227] (XMLDB Developers Guide)

Comment: @chrisis should it help? it seems that i have parsing problem not data getting.

Comment: It avoids the complexities of UTL_HTTP response parsing, character set specification etc.. If it doesn't work then the file being returned isn't valid XML anyway.

Comment: @crhis impressive. getXML function raise the errors but getClob is working. I have tested it right now. can you tell me what's the problem with my xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should work like this

`xml_clob := tableau.Get_Clobfromurl();
s := SUBSTR(xml_clob,INSTR(xml_clob,'<'));`

Answer (score 3):

```
LPX-00209: PI names starting with XML are reserved
```

Appears to happen when there is leading whitespace characters in the XML string.
[See http://oraclequirks.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/lpx-00209-pi-names-starting-with-xml.html](http://oraclequirks.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/lpx-00209-pi-names-starting-with-xml.html).

You should be able to solve it by using:

```
XMLType( TRIM( xml_clob ) )
```

Simplifying your function slightly:

```
create or replace function GET_CLOBFROMURL(
  p_url     varchar2,
  p_charset varchar2 default 'UTF8'
) return clob
is
  req   utl_http.req; 
  resp  utl_http.resp;
  val   varchar2(32547);
  a     clob    := EMPTY_CLOB();
BEGIN
  req := utl_http.begin_request(p_url);
  utl_http.set_body_charset(req, p_charset);
  resp := utl_http.get_response(req);
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      utl_http.read_text(resp, val, 5000);
      a := a||val;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN utl_http.end_of_body THEN
        utl_http.end_response(resp);
        EXIT;
    END;
  END LOOP;
  return a;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN
    utl_http.end_response(resp);
    RAISE;
END;
```

Then the insert can be done entirely in SQL:

```
insert into tableau.VK_ACCOUNTS (
  account_id,
  account_type,
  account_status,
  access_role
)
SELECT proc.account_id,
       proc.account_type,
       proc.account_status,
       proc.access_role   
FROM   ( SELECT tableau.get_clobFromUrl(REQUEST) AS xml FROM DUAL ) c,
       XMLTABLE(
         '/response/account'
          passing XMLType( TRIM( c.xml ) )
          columns account_id     number       path './account_id',
                  account_type   varchar2(20) path './account_type',
                  account_status number       path './account_status',
                  access_role    varchar2(20) path './access_role'
            ) proc
WHERE  c.xml IS NOT NULL
AND    DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH( c.xml ) > 0;
```

Comment: Yes, i have also read about first lines and have already trimed it. Still smth is not working with the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

I know 3 ways to repeat this exception.

1. Prolog exist more than once in xml.

`select xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" ?><?xml version="1.0" ?><a></a>') from dual;`

2. Prolog isn't first element of xml. .

`select xmltype('<a></a><?xml version="1.0" ?>') from dual;`

3. The same situation but here fist line of xml is empty.

`select xmltype(chr(10)||chr(13)||'<?xml version="1.0" ?><a></a>') from dual;`

I think you are facing with problem no. 3. Fast way to get rid of empty first line. Is less known form of function `TRIM`.

`select  xmltype( trim(leading chr(13) from trim(leading chr(10) from trim('                '||chr(10)||chr(13)||' <?xml version="1.0" ?><a></a>')))) from dual;`

`trim(leading chr(13) from trim(leading chr(10) from trim('your_xml_clob')))`

Comment: same errors with modified code                                                            FROM XMLTABLE('response/account' passing (select xmltype( trim(leading chr(13) from trim(leading chr(10) from trim(' '||chr(10)||chr(13)||' <?xml version="1.0" ?><a></a>')))) from dual)
            columns account_id number             path '/account/account_id',
                    account_type varchar2(20)     path '/account/account_type',

Comment: It seems that you are right, because i have tried getClob function (it worked) and getXML function (it rais errors). The problem is with xml but what's the better way to figure out what's the problem

Comment: `select  xmltype(trim(leading chr(13) from trim(leading chr(10) from trim(xml_clob))))  resp FROM dual` did you do this in your code ?

Comment: yes, i have edited `select xmltype(xml_clob)` from original code to your line.

Comment: I think no. Oracle expects PI(<?xml bleble?> in first line of document. If this element exist more than once or not in first line   Error will be raised.

Comment: am i right doing like this `FROM XMLTABLE('response/account' passing (select xmltype(trim(leading chr(13) from trim(leading chr(10) from trim(xml_clob)))) from dual)`